# How can I have Gnome terminal effects for XFCE?

Tags: terminal, styles, xfce

Surely, this is documented somewhere. I for some reason or another cannot find the answer for this.

Most people are wanting to make their terminals completely transparent, I however want the effects where you see the desktop background. I am certain that this is default for gnome. What is this effect called and How can I get this in XFCE?

I was told that installing something like Terminator would resolve this but its just the true transparency which looks messy with a ton of windows and stuff going on.

Here is an example of what I am wanting for XFCE.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxwx7.png

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Xubuntu version that I have solved this issue accidentally. I had to go to manage settings menu -> Window Manager Tweaks ->  Compositor(tab)

and uncheck Enable Display Compositing

Now I can have the terminal just show the desktop background instead of every thing that is messy behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way could be opening your `xfce4-terminal` and going to `Edit->Preferences->Appearance->Background` and then chose a Background image to show instead of a Solid Color or Transparent. [In example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NA8n.png).

Comment: I don't want a picture in the terminal . I want the current desktop background that i have to be in the terminal and if i pan to a tree in that background , i want to see that tree.